# Javascript Function Error From Event Listeners

Tags: javascript

```
function start(){
    var onChangeHandler = function() {
       calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    };
document.getElementById('pac-input').addEventListener('change',onChangeHandler);
document.getElementById('pac-input2').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
}
```

Everytime I change the first element, I get an error because I am suppose to pass two arguments into 'onChangeHandler'. Is there any way I can block my code from producing this error? Once I change the second element, my code works fine since I would have passed two argument into 'onChangeHandler'.

Comment: Where are `directionsService` and `directionsDisplay` supposed to come from?

Comment: var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService; """"""
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer; """""
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

Answer (score 0):

```
function start(){
    var onChangeHandler = function() {
       calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService = '', directionsDisplay = '');
    };
    document.getElementById('pac-input').addEventListener('change',onChangeHandler);
    document.getElementById('pac-input2').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
}
```

Set a default value to the parameters, that is based on your requirement.

Comment: Dangerous! ES6 only! A better solutiuon (for now) would be to set them inside your function `directionsService  = directionsService  || '';` - just for compatibilities sake. EDIT: Actually, this would pass two arguments as empty strings _every time_ since you are passing it `('','')`

Comment: You cannot use parameter defaults when calling a function. You use them when defining a function. What you are doing is setting the (undeclared) variables `directionsService` and `directionsDisplay` to the null string, and then calling `calculateAndDisplayRoute` with those two null strings.

Comment: @torazaburo Exactly (I only realised later this was a function call). This would even nullify any argument and simply break the passing of arguments!

Answer (score 0):

`onChangeHandler` only receives the single `event` from the browser. To pass more things into it, nest it into an anonymous function:

```
function start(){
    var onChangeHandler = function() {
       calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    };
   document.getElementById('pac-input').addEventListener('change',function(e){
        // I do not know what things you want to pass, but it makes no difference for the purposes of this example
        onChangeHandler(e, {});
   }, false);
   document.getElementById('pac-input2').addEventListener('change', function(e){
        onChangeHandler(e, {});
   });
}
```

Why are you nesting `onChangeHandler` anyway? Why not directly call the function inside it? It would look like this and would cut out the middle man:

```
   document.getElementById('pac-input2').addEventListener('change', function(e){
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(e, {});
   });
```